# Revoked visa and given a 5 year ban

Tags: visas, usa, uk, visa-refusals, australian-citizens

[image]

Last year I had been granted a visa to travel to America, once I arrived in America I was stopped at immigration. I had my visa revoked and was given a 5 year ban for America. I want to know if this will affect my chances when entering the UK. Also I know when applying for visa’s that one question is if I have ever been refused a visa, in this circumstance I am unsure of what answer to put as my visa was revoked. Is this the same as been refused a visa?

Comment: What was the reason for the revocation at the border? That sounds pretty unusual, so whatever that was may well affect the UK. Without knowing why, it's hard to say though

Comment: Added the letter of inadmissibility

Comment: It's pretty safe to expect the UK athourities to know about this. However, a ban for the US is **not** a ban for the UK. Voting as off-topic however as it sounds as if you intend to move to the UK - please speak to our sister site, expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm still not sure about the reason. The reason from the photo is one giant block of a single sentence. Also please add whether your passport has any stamps of such that mentions this, and whether you are still using the same passport.

Comment: But my instincts tell me odds are not in your favor with a 5 year ban that happened just 1 year ago.

Comment: Have you ever been deported, removed or otherwise required to leave any country, including the UK in the last 10 years? = yes. And provide your removal letter from the DHS

Comment: My passport has the visa for USA in it, over the top the immigration officers have crosses it out and written "REVOKED" and the section that it has been refused under ie: (7)(A)(i)(ll) . on the next page there is also a stamp with the date of refused entry from boarder security

Comment: The image I added is a photo of the Notice and Order of Expedited Removal. It has further down written: Order of removal under section 235(b)(1)

Comment: @AyeshK The reason appears to be that when asked on landing  "What is your job" the answer was that OP didn't have one, followed by "So how will you support yourself?", the answer was working informally while travelling. Which is of course a pretty flagrant violation of a tourist visa.

Comment: @Chloe90 You have edited this question from "obtaining a working visa" to "when entering the UK". Does this mean you now intend to enter the UK without a visa (as Aus citizens are allowed) or on a visitor visa? Or do you still intend to get a working visa (in which case *you will get better answers* on the expats site linked in the close notice.

Comment: @CMaster still intend on the working visa. I have put my question up on that site and have not received any replies. this site seems to have a wider audience and more chance of having my question answered.

Comment: @Chloe90 We may have a wider audience than [expatriates.se], **but we do not answer such questions**! They are not within our remit, and we usually have no knowledge of the answers anyway.